# PHP error while (1) Importing a non-compound namespace or (2) Importing any namespace to instantiate a class

Tags: php, namespaces

An example of a non-compound PHP namespace:

```
namespace Html;
```

An example of a compound PHP namespace:

```
namespace NS\Html;
```

If I try to import a non-compound PHP namespace, I get the following error:

> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Html' has no effect in /home/public_html/Samples/PHP/Namespaces/ImportNamespace1.php on line 34

Next, I tried using a compound PHP namespace. Now the above error (while trying to use the namespace) disappears, but when I try to instantiate a class in the imported namespace, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Table' not found in /home/public_html/Samples/PHP/Namespaces/ImportNamespace1.php:38

I find that what works is a combination of the following:

1. Use a compound namespace
2. Import the class and not the namespace
   Then, I can instantiate the class without any error along the way.

This is in contrast to what the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) says.

Please note I am using Lightspeed PHP version 7.3.

Here's the code that works:

Namespace definition: must be compound (in File Namespace1.php):

```
<?php

  namespace NS\Html;

  class Table
  {
  }
?>
```

Import and use the class (rather than the namespace) (File ImportNamespace1.php):

```
      use NS\Html\Table As Table;   # Import and alias the class.

      $table = new Table();

?>
```

I'd like to ask:
Has anyone actually used a non-compound namespace and then imported the namespace (rather than the class) to instantiate a class? Kindly provide actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you are looking for?

```php
namespace b {
    class my_class{
        function test() {
            echo 'here';
        }
    }
}

namespace a {
    use b as c;
    // FQN
    (new \b\my_class())->test();
    // Aliased
    (new c\my_class())->test();
}
```

I would personally never write code like this, nor did I know that you can alias a namespace, but it appears to work.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/79Dmg

**Edit**

Here's a version with two files and without bracketed namespaces

```php
<?php

// file b.php
namespace b;

class my_class
{
    function test()
    {
        echo 'here';
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

// file a.php
namespace a;

use b as c;

require_once 'b.php';

// FQN
(new \b\my_class())->test();
// Aliased
(new c\my_class())->test();
```

Comment: Your example works as shown. It uses the 'bracketed syntax' of namespaces. This can't be used when there are 2 source files. Then, the unbracketed syntax must be used. (Here, the 'namespace' declaration must be at the top of the file.) There your example gives error 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'A\Table' not found'.

Comment: The bracketed syntax works regardless of the number of files. I personally find it weird to see a single file wrapped in a giant namespace but I've seen it when people from other languages come to PHP. Regardless, I just tried the above, both unwrapped and in different files and it works the exact same. I can post an updated sample above if you want that.

Comment: Can you post your new example showing 'unbracketed syntax' + 2 files, please? I'd appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: @SSteven, I updated my post above with that

Comment: I have tested your solution at my end, including several variants. They all work perfectly. Thanks.